# Int main redefinition error on C4droid

Tags: android, c++, gcc, g++

I was using c4droid(c++)(g++ + bionic compiler) on my android device, the code that was earlier working, when run after 2-3 hours, gave the error!!

Seriously, don't know anything about the error, but one observation, on re installing the app, i saw the problem going away, but temporarily!

***code***

```
    // program with file handling search , display and modify functions
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    ofstream f("bank.dat", ios::app);

     int n = 0, flag = 0;
     struct bac
         {
           char name[10];
           char amt[5];
          } s;

    void add()
    { 
        cout << "\nenter the details ";
        cin >> s.name >> s.amt;
        f.write((char *)&s, sizeof(bac));

    }

    void ser()
    {
        ifstream fa("bank.dat");
        fa.seekg(0);
        char x[10];
        cout << "\nenter value to be searched ";
        cin >> x;

        while (fa && flag == 0)
        {
            n++;
        fa.read((char *)&s, sizeof(bac));
        if (strcmp(s.name, x) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nfound";
        cout << "\nAmount " << s.amt;
    }


}

void mod()
{
    ser();
    cout<<" "<<n;
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        f.seekp((n - 1) * sizeof(bac));
    //  cout<<f.tellp();
        cout<<"\nnew details ";
        add();
        }
    }


    int main()
    {f.seekp(0);
        int ch;

            cout << "\nBANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM \n";
            cout << "enter choice ";
            cout << "\n1.add\n2.search\n3.delete and overwrite ";
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch == 1)
            {
                add();
            }
            if (ch == 2)
            {
                ser();
            }
            if (ch == 3)
            {
                mod();
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

***UPDATE***

even this program gives the same error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

***ERROR*** error: redefinition of 'int main()' compilation terminated due to -Wfatal - errors –

The code is logically incorrect , but did used to compile!
I need to know what is exactly causing the problem, and that too when the code was earlier compiling and running!

Comment: What was the error?  Was there an error message? Did it fail at compile time or at run time? What is the relevance of "int main redefinition" in your title?

Comment: when i run the program , i get the Int main redifinition error @KeithThompson

Comment: people who are voting down the question at least do mention the reason !

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the *exact* error message. Something like `int main redefinition` (note: `int`, not `Int`, and `redefinition`, not redifinition`) is more likely to come from the linker. Perhaps your environment links the program automatically? And you haven't given us a hint what your source code looks like. Could it be you've defined `main` twice?

Comment: now i do think that i have provided enough details , please reopen the question!

Comment: Exact error language : error: refefinition of 'int main()' compilation terminated due to -Wfatal - errors

Comment: @KeithThompson details provided

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the exact error message, don't re-type it. (I strongly doubt that the authors of the compiler misspelled "redefinition"). And you said it fails when you run the program, but that's clearly a compile-time error; which is it? Exactly what steps did you perform immediately prior to the error?

Comment: The code you posted should fail compilation on the call to `strcmp` because you're missing the `#include <cstring>` that's necessary to provide its definition. (Maybe `<string>` includes `<cstring>` on your implementation?) But it defines `main` exactly once, so you shouldn't be getting a redefinition error. There's something  you're not telling us. Don't give us information a little bit at a time as we ask for it; you need to show us all your code, and tell us exactly what you're doing before the error happens. (I didn't downvote you, but I'm sure that's why others have done so.)

Comment: @KeithThompson can't copy and paste the exact message, its on my android device !! 

also i am very sorry for all my typos!!!!!!!

EXACT ERROR: redefinition of 'int main()'

Comment: @KeithThompson i dont think it is an error due to <string> coz even he simplest programs do not work!!

Comment: I do think it is a compiler based error !!

I mailed the developer, and this was his reply

***How are your sources named?
Seems like you have a source code named like a system header in the same directory with your program.***        so i re installed the app and made a new folder , and voila !! now it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I most probably had a source code named like a system header in the same directory with your program .
Re installing the app and renaming and transferring the files to a different location did the trick